# Remove number between end of row and new space

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to remove the numbers at the beginning of a row inside quotation marks.

```
> g<-"My name is Paul.\nI like playing football.\n\"55012\" And that's all."
> cat(g)
My name is Paul.
I like playing football.
"55012" And that's all.
> gsub("[\r\n]\"+[[:digit:]][^[[:space:]]]*"," ",g)
[1] "My name is Paul.\nI like playing football. 012\" And that's all."
```

This should work, but I don't know why only `\n"55` is being replaced and not the entire number.

Comment: Give a `+` after `[[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the bracket expression with a couple of redundant `[...]`. `[^[[:space:]]]` is a sequence of `[^[[:space:]]` and `]`  patterns and matches any char other than `[` and whitespace and then a `]` char.

However, even that is not enough to fully fix the issue.

You may use

```
gsub("(^|\n)\"+[0-9]+\"+\\s*","\\1", g)
```

See the [R demo](https://tio.run/##FcnBCoJAEAbgu0/xM5c0NTTwEHTx2CHo3hSMZOvSNkq7HoTefcvbB98nRoNjCTovUHn3sB4Xmd2O9QRnXz0mJ4tVg@c4hk7cOkxNU9V7JrT6QBgkbDzWosT4uUspvX9ZM6b8WpWHW/4Hs99SQcw1FSZLYvwB)

**Pattern details**

- `(^|\n)` - start of string or a newline captured in Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern)
- `\"+` - one or more double quotes
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `\"+` - one or more double quotes
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqpdg7/1)